# Comparison of normality tests results - Histogram and PP Plot

Tags: normal-distribution, normality-assumption

I have a data-set that contains 251 data points. I used minitab software to test for normality and  first plotted a histogram which gave the result as under.

[image]

The above plot resembles an almost a normal distribution.However when i plot a PP Plot using Anderson-Darling test i get the significance level below 0.005 which makes me reject the null hypothesis i.e the distribution is normal.

[image]

Below is the attached PP plot.

Why are the two plots giving different conclusions ? 
Is my data normal ?

Comment: Both plots are showing you essentially the same thing (though the histogram has too few bins which obscures the important detail more than a better choice would). No, your data are plainly not from a normal distribution, there's a clear spike of values at 10 (though that may not matter a great deal in some situations). Why do you care whether the data are from a normal distribution?

Answer (score 1):

From both plots, it's clear that you have something very close to normal except for the clump of observations at AFINN = 10.

Why are you testing whether the data are normally distributed?  I ask because 1) Many people incorrectly assume that the data must be normally distributed to do linear regression and 2) How much non-normality can be tolerated depends on why you need normality in the first place (if you do need it).

Also, what are AFINN scores and why is there a clump at 10?  This looks like a ceiling effect.

Comment: The AFINN are the avg sentiment scores of sentiment keywords which are graded on the basis of polarity i.e positive, negative, neutral on a scale of 1-10 We are trying to detect fake reviews out of a sample of 251 reviews based on the logic that observations with AFINN scores close to the mean i.e normally distributed would be tagged as 'Not Fake'. Adding to that , Reviews with AFINN Scores beyond 2 Standard deviations would be tagged as outliers.

Comment: I agree with Peter. There is no reason to suppose that a normal distribution is even a natural reference distribution here. Your data are bounded and the upper bound is often attained. That's enough to rule out normality or not? as either an interesting or a useful question, as the answer is just no. Looking at your data is important, but the histogram alone without the superimposed normal is helpful and almost sufficient.

Comment: Strictly that's not a PP plot at all. It's a QQ plot, even though that the normal quantiles are labelled by their cumulative probabilities in percent terms. A PP plot has limits of 0 and 1 on both axes. The historic term "probability plot" is still used for quantile-quantile plots, and indeed that carry-over can be confusing.

Comment: From your comment @DeeponGhoseRoy that is NOT a good way to go about this.  Please ask a different question with your actual problem (which is in your comment).  Detecting fake reviews will be tricky and a simple solution like this isn't right.

Comment: @Peter FLom, Sir have added a question as a separate one. Kindly have a look.https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/309574/detection-of-fake-reviews-using-the-normality-assumption