# Detection of Fake reviews using the normality assumption

Tags: normal-distribution, normality-assumption

As a follow up question to the following post on stack exchange, kindly read the following :

[Comparison of normality tests results - Histogram and PP Plot](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/309416/comparison-of-normality-tests-results-histogram-and-pp-plot/309422?noredirect=1#comment588094_309422)

My dataset of reviews contains 251 data points.The AFINN are the avg sentiment scores of sentiment keywords which are graded on the basis of polarity i.e positive, negative, neutral on a scale of 1-10.
The distribution is almost normal when plotted on a histogram. We are trying to detect fake reviews based on the logic that observations with AFINN scores close to the mean i.e normally distributed would be tagged as 'Not Fake'. Adding to that , Reviews with AFINN Scores beyond 2 Standard deviations would be tagged as outliers will be discarded.We are assuming that if majority of people are expressing an opinion about something (Indicated by within 2 standard deviations , it must be genuine
The only exception to this assumption is that data points that fall within 2 standard deviations could also indicative of collective opinion spamming by a group usually paid by brands to write extreme opinions.  But that is not a worry if the sample size is large enough.

Adding to the above,

The detected fake reviews would be further analyzed using the mean and standard deviation. Those reviews with a mean score of its own words >8.5 and a standard deviation between 0-0.99 and also reviews with the mean score of <2.5 and standard deviation between 0-0.99 will be tagged as fake..The reason for this is we are assuming that opinion spammers either give extreme opinions to either amplify/malign a particular product.

My question is the following :

Is our logic correct and our method to detect fake reviews using the two steps on the right track ?

Comment: Potentially throwing out anything that is in the most extreme 5% of opinions (2.5% best and 2.5% worst), seems like it could be a non ideal idea.

Comment: [Almost 90% Germans endorsed Hitler befor the WW2](http://www.nytimes.com/learning/general/onthisday/big/0819.html), he must have been a good choice and the remaining 10% must have been wrong, didn't it..?

Comment: It's hard to identify any statistical logic here. If you want to identify a middle ground, that is necessarily between extreme opinions. But if you want to know what's fake, there is no statistical substitute for independently checking what is correct. If that's not possible, there is no white magic from statistics to help.

Comment: To detect spam, I guess the best thing to do is gather a dataset of reviews, of which you know which reviews are spam and which are not (i.e. Labeled data). You can then train a model (svm or some similar machine learning method) that learns how to distinguish between real and fake messages.. probably not the answer you were hoping for.